# How to select integers divisible by 3 from list of first 100 non-negative integers?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to select numbers divisible by 3 from the first 100 non-negative integers (i.e., 0 to 100). Currently, I am experimenting with Quotient, Select, List and Mod commands but I am unable to accomplish this task. Please help.

Comment: Use Range to create the iniitial list of non-negative integers (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Range.html). Select is the way you pick elements that satisfy some predicate (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html). Then you need to supply that predicate to Select. The function Divisible will work well here (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Divisible.html). Try combining those functions, and if you still are running into trouble, post the code you tried with your  question.

Comment: In addition to the comment above, consider that a number would be divisible by 3 if the remainder of the division (obtained with `Mod`) is zero.

Comment: `Select[Range[0, 100], Mod[#, 3] == 0 &]`

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to use [Cases](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) and [Divisible](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Divisible.html) in the following way:

```
Cases[Range[0, 100],x_ /; Divisible[x, 3]]
```

> [image: div]

Answer (score 3):

```
Range[0, 100][[1 ;; -1 ;; 3]]

Range[0, 100][[;; ;; 3]]
```

Comment: `Range[0, 100, 3]`.